# how number of thread should be accepted via command line using pthread?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I am writting an application that has multiple threads in Linux environment using C or python. I am using pthread for that.  But How number of threads should be accepted via command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you handle command line arguments by having `main` take two arguments,

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

in which `argc` is the number of command line arguments (including the program itself) and `argv` is a pointer to a memory location where `argc-1` pointers to strings with the actual arguments are located. Example:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("The program was executed as %s.\n", argv[0]);
  printf("The arguments were:\n");
  for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
  return 0;
}
```

Let's now assume that your program takes a single command line argument, an integer telling you how many threads to spawn. The integer is given as a string, so we have to convert it using `atoi`:

```
if (argc != 2)
{
  printf("Need exactly one argument!\n");
  return 1;
}
int num_threads = atoi(argv[1]); // Convert first argument to integer.
if (num_threads < 1)
{
  printf("I'll spawn no less than 1 thread!\n");
  return 2;
}
```

Now what you do is simply create an array of thread handles,

```
pthread_t* threads = malloc(num_threads*sizeof(pthread_t));
```

and use it to store the thread handles as you start `num_threads` number of threads using `pthread_create`.

If you are not familiar with pthreads at all, I recommend [this short tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pthred.html).

Comment: threads = malloc(num_threads*sizeof(pthread_t));
 tr = pthread_create( &threads, NULL, NULL, NULL);                         passing argument 1 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type (warning it shows)

Comment: thanks, Yes i am not familiar with pthread.how should i do for sleep for random intervals Once awake, write its own name in the string

Comment: Regarding the code in your comment: &threads means the address of the pointer threads. You want &threads[i] (the address of the i'th element of the array threads) when creating the i'th thread.

Comment: I would post your question about sleeping and waking at random intervals as a separate stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 2):

If you were using a threading framework like [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openmp), then this is all handled automatically simply by setting the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`.

But if you're implementing threads "manually", you'll need to do it the way most runtime configuration is done: either by parsing `argv[]`, or by setting an environment variable and using `getenv()`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you would just pass it like any other argument. I've used code similar to the following in projects before to specify fixed thread counts. This is fairly simple but suitable for situations where you don't need the full power of thread pooling (though you could just as easily set a minimum and maximum thread count the same way).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define THRD_DFLT  5
#define THRD_MIN   2
#define THRD_MAX  20

static int numThreads = 0;
int main (int argCount, char *argVal[]) {
    if (argCount > 1)
        numThreads = atoi (argVal[1]);
    if ((numThreads < 5) || (numThreads > THRD_MAX)) {
        printf ("Number of threads outside range %d-%d, using %d\n",
            THRD_MIN, THRD_MAX, THRD_DFLT);
        numThreads = THRD_DFLT;
    }
    :
    :
```

Comment: Minor stylistic quibble: Isn't it standard practice to always use `argc` and `argv`, for clarity and consistency?

Comment: Actually I normally use `argCount` and `argVal` since I prefer more readable names (the same reason I rarely use `i` as a counter in real code), but I was in a hurry :-)